# How to declare mapping for nested fields in Elasticsearch to allow for storing different types?

Tags: elasticsearch, types, nested, mapping

In essence, I want my mapping to be as schemaless as possible, but allow for nested types and being able to store data that may have different types:

When I try to add a document where some fields have different types of values, I get an error like this:

"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "mapper [data.customData.value] of different type, current_type [long], merged_type [text]"

This can easily be solved by mapping the field value to text (or create it dynamically by first inserting a document with only text). However, I would like to avoid having a schema. Perhaps having all of the fields nested in customData to be set to text? How do I do that?

I had the problem earlier, but then it started working after accidentally managing to get a dynamical mapping that worked (since everything was regarded as text. I was later made aware of this problem since I needed to change the mapping to allow for nested types.

Documents with this kind of data are troublesome to store successfully:

```
"customData": [
        {
          "value": "some_text",
          "key": "some_text"
        },
        {
          "value": 0,
          "key": "some_text"
        }
      ]
```

A part of the mapping that works:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "data": {
                        "properties": {
                            "customData": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "ignore_above": 256
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "ignore_above": 256
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "some_list": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "some_field": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In essence, I want the mapping to be as schemaless as possible, but allow for nested types and being able to store data that may have different types:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "type": "object"
        },
        "somee_list": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So what would be the best approach to go about this problem?

Comment: Store data as a text will take a lot of memory but will be searchable. You only works with words and want to have a kind of string dictionnary or you also want to work with geolocation, range, date fields?

Comment: At the moment the requirements for the searching capabilities are quite vague. At the moment it seems as if possible, the following comparators should be supported:
">=", ">", "<=", "<", "!=", "=".

By indexing as keyword (instead of text as I first thought of) I should be able to allow for "!=" and "=".

Is there any way to keep the types and try to handle cases where types do not match?

Comment: Elasticsearch index data according to their type. What s why it is so fast. Es philosophie is to build your own search engine. If you want somehting generic, try something like this:
"key": keyword (and use as keyword something to know his type like "int_age", 
"value_key": keyword
"type_key": keyword (= one es type like long, datetime, text, location, int, keyword....)
"value_long": long
"value_date": date
"value_text": test
"value_location" : location
...

Comment: So you could store the key value type you want, if you use a java - .net or another high level client, you should be able to build generic querry easily according to the type of the field.

Comment: That is a good idea! I should probably do that if given the time. Until then I think that I will treat every field as text or keyword. However,  I do not manage to find a way to do that. What would be the best approach for only having one property-type for all objects in customData?